# Confidence Interval for Population Proportion. Clopper-Pearson Interval

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I am sincerely stuck on this problem. Please help

alpha is 0.05

[image]

Comment: You have a binomial : defective/non-defective, with p=.08 , and sample size =25. Do you know how to use Normal approx here for a Normal interval?

Comment: @gary, Hi Gary, I understand this is a sample with a binomal RV, but I don't know how to derive a CI for it to be honest

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: @Biu, Hi, just by doing an interval as you would for a Normal, with mean =(25)(0.08) and s.d $p(1-p)$.

Comment: @Gary, p=2/25=0.08, so the success proportion refers to the number of defective boards, but the question is asking to find the *CI for the true proportion of circuit boards in the lot from which the sample was drawn*, is it referring to the non-defective boards?

Comment: @Biu: Yes, the sample data is used to estimate the Population data for the same parameter. And then $s.d=(0.02)(0.98)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A - Confidence interval with a Normal approximation:

$$\hat p\pm z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\ \sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1-\hat p)}{n}},\ \ \hat p=\frac{s}{n}$$

in which $s$ is the number of successes (defects in this case) and $n$ the number of boards. $z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ is the quantile $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$ of a standard Normal (e.g. close to 1.96 for $\alpha=0.05$, a 95% confidence probability).

Making the substitutions $s=2$, $n=25$ $\alpha=0.05$ leads to

$$\hat p\pm z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\ \sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1-\hat p)}{n}}=[-0.026,0.186]$$

Problem: this is a crude approximation, as $n=25$, the lower limit for the "true" frequency of defects is negative (-0.026), a non-sense.

B - Confidence interval - Clopper Pearson  (see for instance, Bilder & Loughin [2014] Categorical Data Analysis with R - CRC, page 15, for details)

This interval is exact and usually defined by quantiles of a Beta distribution by

$$[\text{QBeta}(\alpha/2, s,n-s+1), \text{QBeta}(1-\alpha/2, s+1,n-s)]$$

in the expression, QBeta is the quantile function of a beta, and the parameters in each function represents, respectively, the probability for the quantile, the first parameter of the Beta, and the second parameter of the beta.

Using $s=2$, $n=25$, $\alpha=0.05$ and the Beta quantile function from R, that is *qbeta*:

$$[\text{qbeta}(0.025,2,24), \text{qbeta}(0.975,3,23)]=[0.0098,0.2603].$$

In this case the limits for the confidence interval, 0.0098 and 0.2603, are not negative. It is a large interval due to a low $n$ (lots of uncertainty on the true frequency of defects).

Comment: Thank you, this is really great, I was struggling with the Clopper Pearson, we had to study it on our own, and it is kicking my butt. Appreciate it.

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373154/large-sample-confidence-interval